# Idiom about not being useful

Tags: idiom-requests

I am trying to remember an idiom I have heard before but can't remember.  It goes something like:

> They couldn't figure out how to [***insert thing here***] if they flipped it over to read the instructions.

I'm pretty sure *thing* is something that simply requires being turned upside down to be accomplished, but google hasn't been much help.

Does anyone know the idiom I'm thinking of?

Comment: Hourglass/egg-timer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A slightly bowdlerized version of what I believe you’re thinking of is “He couldn’t pour water out of a boot with the directions printed on the bottom of the heel.” There’s more discussion about it [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/555007/the-origin-or-rough-timeframe-for-the-quip-about-pouring-piss-out-of-a-boot#:%7E:text=Pour%20piss%20out%20of%20a%20boot%20if%20the%20directions%20were,and%20the%20toes%20cut%20out.&text=Pour%20piss%20out%20of%20a%20boot%2C%20and%20if%20he%20did,he%27d%20step%20in%20it.).

Answer (score 5):

> They **couldn't make heads or tails of it** until they flipped it over to read the instructions.

> **not make head or/nor tail of** (idiom)
> variants: or *US* **not make heads or/nor tails (out) of**
>
> *informal*
>
> To be unable to understand (something)
>
> *I couldn't make heads or tails of her reaction.*
>
> *His handwriting was so bad that we couldn't make heads or tails out of it.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/not%20make%20heads%20or%20tails%20of)

> **make heads or tails (out) of (someone or something)**
>
> To understand someone or something. This phrase is usually used in the
> negative to convey the opposite.
>
> *After spending hours working with the new piece of software, I still **could not make heads or tails out of it**.*
>
> *I **can't make heads or tails of** that new guy in accounting. Sometimes, he's really friendly, and then other times he acts like he's never met
> me before.* [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+heads+or+tails+(out)+of+(someone+or+something))

Comment: It makes more sense when it's written like this: "They couldn't make heads or tails of it until they flipped it [...]". "They couldn't figure out" already implies that they couldn't understand.

Comment: @Justin Agreed, thanks. In fact, Farlex defines *make heads or tails of*, but adds that it's usually used in the negative.